# Parsing tags from input annotation file and pasting to the final output file

Tags: r

My input annotation file is as such

```
GEO_ID  Title   Platform    Description Group   Sample_Name
GSM344422   Healthy-8   GPL20301    human Leukocytes_2016-06-01 Leukocytes_at_gestational_age_of_18-23wk_from_healthy_fetal_hearts  Healthy
GSM3444233  R-A7    GPL20301    human Leukocytes_2018-06-04 Leukocytes_at_gestational_age_of_18-23wk_from_healthy_fetal_hearts  Healthy
GSM344434   R2-FITC GPL20301    human Leukocytes_2018-06-04 Leukocytes_at_gestational_age_of_18-23wk_from_healthy_fetal_hearts  Healthy
GSM3444235  CHB-4   GPL20301    human Leukocytes_2016-06-01 Leukocytes_at_gestational_age_of_19-23wk_from_fetal_hearts_with_congenital_heart_block_(CHB)    Heartblock
GSM344236   CHB_Luekocytes  GPL20301    human Leukocytes_2017-11-22 Leukocytes_at_gestational_age_of_19-23wk_from_fetal_hearts_with_congenital_heart_block_(CHB)    Heartblock
GSM344237   CHB-F   GPL20301    human Leukocytes_2018-06-04 Leukocytes_at_gestational_age_of_19-23wk_from_fetal_hearts_with_congenital_heart_block_(CHB)    Heartblock
-----   -----   -----   -----   -----   
Comparison  Trat    Ctrl    Title   Paired  Tags
1   Leukocytes_at_gestational_age_of_19-23wk_from_fetal_hearts_with_congenital_heart_block_(CHB)    Leukocytes_at_gestational_age_of_18-23wk_from_healthy_fetal_hearts  Leukocytes from fetal hearts with congenital heart block _vs_ healthy   FALSE   Primary cells|Leukocytes|Heart|Fetus|Disease vs. normal|Congenital heart block
```

My final output file small subset looks like this which is generated after analysis step between multiple sample comparisons.

```
Bioset summary = Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions vs. Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions

Data pre-processing = FASTQ files were downloaded from Sequence Read Archive (SRA). No other preprocessing was performed.

Analysis summary = Reads are aligned to mm10 using Dragen RNA 3.9.5. The differential methylation calling is done by methylKit R package using following parameters: qvalue - 0.01 and methylation difference (%) - 10

Test samples = Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions(total replicates = 5)
Control samples = Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions(total replicates = 5)


chromosome      start   stop    % differential  p-Value q-Value
2       98662301        98663300        11.4222829122048        0       0
2       98662401        98663400        13.6033864634586        0       0
```

What i need is this in my final output whatever is in the Tag column of the annotation file should be appended to the final file.

So I would like this to be generic mean it should always pick the `**Tag**` column based on whatever **input annotation** it is.

```
Bioset summary = Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions vs. Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions
    
    Data pre-processing = FASTQ files were downloaded from Sequence Read Archive (SRA). No other preprocessing was performed.
    
    Analysis summary = Reads are aligned to mm10 using Dragen RNA 3.9.5. The differential methylation calling is done by methylKit R package using following parameters: qvalue - 0.01 and methylation difference (%) - 10
    
    Test samples = Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions(total replicates = 5)
    Control samples = Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions(total replicates = 5)

Tags:Primary cells|Leukocytes|Heart|Fetus|Disease vs. normal|Congenital heart block


 
    chromosome      start   stop    % differential  p-Value q-Value
    2       98662301        98663300        11.4222829122048        0       0
    2       98662401        98663400        13.6033864634586        0       0
```

Any suggestion or help how to go about it?

Comment: I'm guessing your original file is in fixed width format or possibly in TSV format, In any case your display of it here is not useful for people trying to replicate your experience or demonstrate a solution.

Comment: Now that I've ascertained that the original file was TSV format, I'm now wondering if the request is for a method to take the input of the second code-block and insert a line or two containing the "tags" between the lines that have "=" signs in them and the header line that starts with "chromosome"?

Comment: @IRTFM yes my original file is in tsv format.

Comment: @IRTFM actually yes the second code block which contains the tag information which i need to append it to my final output file before the chromosome

Answer (score 1):

If you have the first code block entered as a data.frame named `dat` and the second code block entered as a character vector named `inp` then this will produce the desired result:

```
c(inp[1:8], paste0(dat[8:9, "Sample_Name"], collapse=":"), inp[10:length(inp) ] )
#----------------
[1] "Bioset summary = Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions vs. Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions"         
 [2] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [3] "Data pre-processing = FASTQ files were downloaded from Sequence Read Archive (SRA). No other preprocessing was performed."                                                                                             
 [4] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [5] "Analysis summary = Reads are aligned to mm10 using Dragen RNA 3.9.5. The differential methylation calling is done by methylKit R package using following parameters: qvalue - 0.01 and methylation difference (%) - 10"
 [6] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [7] "Test samples = Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions(total replicates = 5)"                                                                                                 
 [8] "Control samples = Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions(total replicates = 5)"                                                                       
 [9] "Tags:Primary cells|Leukocytes|Heart|Fetus|Disease vs. normal|Congenital heart block"                                                                                                                                   
[10] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[11] "chromosome      start   stop    % differential  p-Value q-Value"                                                                                                                                                       
[12] "2       98662301        98663300        11.4222829122048        0       0"                                                                                                                                             
[13] "2       98662401        98663400        13.6033864634586        0       0"
```

There is no "Tag" column *per se*. The column name with the value "Tag" and tag values is "Sample_Name". If you don't want the line numbers then use `cat` or `print` with the appropriate parameter to display it to the console. The line numbers are not actually in the resulting object.